# How to create a regex for a number character and the symbol -?

Tags: javascript, regex

It has a logic, where the user types in the input and at the same time the mask occurs, in this case, two conditions can happen:

1. If he is entering a monetary value, only the numbers entered will be accepted and he will fill in for me the "." or "," according to the decimal place (this code is not here), example:

   "BRL 1,000.00"
2. If he is typing a percentage value, the same thing happens as in case (1), but he inserts the following, for example:

   "1,000.00%"

Cool.. This works, however, now I'm trying to rack his brain for him to do this, if he wants a negative number, he should type the minus sign (-), regardless of where the selection pointer is in the input , this sign must be to the left of the first number, for example:

```
"BRL -1,000.00"
"-1,000.00%"
```

I'm trying to do this with regex, I managed to release the minus sign (-), however, I can't put it to the left of the last number or block it to be typed only once by the user, so what happens is:

```
"BRL 0.0-"
"BRL -.11"
```

Code:

```
value = value
      .toString()
      .replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '')
      .replace(/^0+(?!$)/, '')
      .substring(0, maxNumber);
```

Comment: não percebo, testei do meu lado e funciona, quando coloco `BRL -1,000.00` como entrada o regex devolve `-100000`. Não é isso que vc quer?

Answer (score 0):

I really can't understand what you want (after reading your text twice), but on my side it works as I guess you would expect.

Just run the snippet

```js
const convert = (value) => value
  .toString()
  .replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '')
  .replace(/^0+(?!$)/, '')
  .substring(0, 50);
  
console.log(convert("BRL -1,000.00"))
console.log(convert("-1,000.00%"))
```

Do you want to remove the minus sign, is that?